# Polygon overlap queries very slow

Tags: sql, duplicates, postgis, overlap

I try to do 2 spatial queries to detect overlap, using the function ST_Overlaps to detect a partial overlap and the function ST_Equal to detect duplicate polygons. Both are extremely slow on my PostGIS database of +60k polygons. It takes up to an 1 hour to run each query... I use an INDEX to speed up the process, but it seems this is barely make the process more efficient. This is my query with ST_Equals to detect duplicate polygons:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS indexpol ON tree_registration_areas USING gist(polygon);

cluster tree_registration_areas using indexpol;

WITH duplicate_polygons AS (
SELECT
a.identifier AS identifier_a,
b.identifier AS identifier_b
FROM tree_registration_areas a, tree_registration_areas b
WHERE ST_EQUALS(a.polygon::geometry, b.polygon::geometry)
AND a.identifier != b.identifier)
```

Any idea what could be the reason for the slowness of my queries? It cannot be that the 60k polygons cause this issue? If so, is there a way to do it more efficient?

Comment: That query is incomplete. Also, I don't see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output.

Comment: Why are you casting to `geometry`? If the column is `geography`, so is the index and it won't be used on the cast.

Comment: Also,  `a.identifier != b.identifier` will give you two rows for each difference (a != b and b != a). You can use just a < b

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the feedback and help. In the end, the issue was caused by a wrong index. So the solution of @JGH worked. The query now only needs +1 minutes to complete instead of a +1 hour. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, the feedback of @GregStef was interesting, but in the end, I do need to detect 'cross differences', so I used a !=b  instead of a < b.

Comment: Well, I don't think you need a != b: If a NOT EQUALS b <=> b NOT EQUALS a. Besides (I can tell from years of experience in running such queries), not having the same pair twice in your results is more manageable - and faster, in case of many differences.

Comment: @GregStef: I need a list of duplicates where both duplicates should appear. So if polygons a, b and c are duplicates, then I need a list were a, b and c appear as duplicates, not only a or b or c. I will check your solution again to see if this works for me, since my database is growing and query speed will become an important issue in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not trying to force anything here, I'm just saying that the approach a<b works better than a<>b, especially in large datasets with many differences. FWIW, if we have 3 equal geometries, respectively with ids id1,id2,id3 and id1 < id2 < id3, then my approach will give you 3 results: id1-id2, id1-id3, id2-id3 - you always get all your differences.